# Passing parameters to dynamic named function

Tags: vbscript

I want to call a function with a dynamic name, which can be done with `Eval`:

```
fName = "TestFunction"
Call Eval(fName)
```

This works great, but how do I pass parameters to this function call? Something like this doesn't work:

```
Call Eval(fName)(Param1, Param2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Eval` you need to prepare the code to execute

```
Call Eval(fName & "(" & Param1 & "," & Param2 & ")" )
```

What you are trying needs `GetRef`

```
Call GetRef(fName)(Param1, Param2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Add(int1, int2)
    Add = int1 + int2
End Function

intSum = Eval("Add(1, 2)")
' or...
intSum = Eval("Add(" & intParam1 & ", " & intParam2 & ")")
```